# Why in the electroweak theory is symmetry 'hidden' at low energies? But energy is not a function of time $E=h\nu$?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, standard-model, symmetry-breaking, electroweak

Electroweak theory argues that the *symmetry* that accompanies them is obvious only to the high energies, while it is hidden with inferior energies. Scientist use top analogy to explain this concept but for me this image is improper, it does not explain well why at low energies the symmetry breaks down
We speak about Higgs Mechanism/Particle, detected at CERN, but at low energies it is not possible to explain the same bond because the energies with which it is working are in this case *extremely low*.
But.. what exactly means 'low' energies ? 
I do not understand why weakening the low energies
So, for example, what is that binds to low energies, such as the neutrino and photon at 0,05 eV ?

Why is it hidden at low energy? Why can not you find this hidden symmetry? What is it that prevents you from detecting this channel between neutrino-photon (example) ?
The *high energy* that is spoken to me, genuinely, seems more a problem related to managing the time of events than a problem of high or low energies (or mass which is a function of energy, not just an intrinsic property).

Please illuminate me, I do not understand the function of this difference (high-low energy) and because the new physics is geared to using high energies.

Source: [link](http://www.fisicaparticelle.altervista.org/elettrodebole.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electroweak symmetry in the  standard model of particle physics came from experimental observations .

[In the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics the three generations of quarks have different masses, the three generations of leptons have different masses, and the weak interaction is mediated by very massive  bosons (Z, W+/-), whereas the electromagnetic one by zero mass photons.

[image: elem]

The [weak interactions in the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Electroweak_sector), followed the symmetry of SU(2) with the massive exchange bosons  and the electromagnetic of U(1), with the zero mass photon.

Ever since Maxwell unified electricity and magnetism, the goal of seeking unification of forces is a driving force in modeling particle data.

The [Higgs mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) is a way of unifying weak and electromagnetic interactions at very high energies, making the exchange bosons  mass equal to zero before the symmetry breaking energy. Below  that energy the W and Z bosons acquire their mass and the photon remains zero mass, the single force becoming two, weak and electromagnetic.

The electroweak part of the standard model describes all the data at low, laboratory energies, but offers a mathematical reasoning that allows for unification. The  program of finding a unified field theory for all forces  goes on, and here is the laboratory of the [history of the universe](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/unify.html#c1) as is described by the Big Bang model.

[image: universe]

Unification of all forces would mean that one coupling would describe an interaction between the elementary particles in the table.

An experimental indication that as energies go higher the different couplings converge can be [seen here.](http://www.clab.edc.uoc.gr/materials/pc/proj/running_alphas.html)

[image: running couplings]

So that is where higher and higher energy experiments in particle physics lead us, to validate  one mathematical unifying model at very  high energies. The recent discovery of the Higgs at the LHC is a validation of the model.

Comment: mm.. when you say *making the exchange bosons mass equal to zero before the symmetry breaking energy* it seems like to a method to generate photons. Why application is used Higgs Mechanism ? To make energy ? I understand unification but I don't understand which technical implementation in physics you can do knowing this mechanism.
What advantages or tools we can build by knowing this mechanism (
For example in the biomedical field or security)?

Comment: The mechanism happened at very high energies, look at the graph. We live at a broken electroweak universe where W and Z have mass, and only the photon is massless.  The advantage of knowing the mechanism is that it allows us to build the standard model that can predict practically all the data coming from high energy physics experiments, and is a stepping stone to an  inclusive theory . Advantage? If one had asked Maxwell "what advantage does uniting electricity and magnetism gives us in biomedical field or security" he would have answered "none" it allows us to fit the measurements of

Comment: electricity and magnetism and electric circuits. Of course now, two hundred years later, the theory of electromagnetism is involved in security and biomedicine and all the technological civilization that has been built up knowing how to calculate things. Including this forum we can discuss virtually.

Answer (score 1):

Electroweak symmetry is indeed broken at low energies.

You point out that energy isn't a function of time - so why can it be that we say the Universe obeyed a symmetry in the past, but that it is spontaneously broken now?

Well, the electroweak symmetry was broken when the Universe underwent a (probably second-order) phase-transition. Like any phase-transition, such as water boiling or freezing, this involved a change in the ground state. At low temperature, a ground state that breaks electroweak symmetry is favoured, just as at low temperature, a ground state that makes water turn to ice is favoured.

Like phase-transitions of water, the electroweak phase transition occurred at a particular temperature. The temperature was probably very high ($T\sim 100\,\text{GeV}$, which I think is about $T\sim 10^{15}\,\text{C}$). When we say electroweak symmetry is broken at low energy, we mean low temperatures.

The Universe began with a hot big-bang, in which electroweak symmetry was unbroken, then cooled to $T\sim -270\,\text{C}$, spontaneously breaking electroweak symmetry.